# Monte Carlo Simulation for DCF Model in R

Tags: r, simulation, montecarlo

I am trying to create a function where Monte Carlo Simulation is applied to two of the variables in a DCF Model in R Studio. It supposed to take a first value `FCF_0` and applied to it a specific growth `FCF_ 0*(1 + growth)`, which is the first input variable until period 6, each period takes the last FCF to keep growing. After that I would like to discount it as well to get the present value which would be `FCFn*(1/((1+WACC)^n))`. Where `WACC` is the second variable to simulate.

So far I have the function to calculate the FCF but with a vector of specifics values of growth, which is the following:

What I am trying so far to create this function is this, but I think is bad.

Could you please help me to understand how to create both simulations and if it is neccesary for me to create two functions or in one function I can do everything? I would expect from the function to give the sum of all present values and each sum would be an element in a vector of 10.000 simulations. I am new at this and even though I have read almost for two weeks, I don't get how to create these simulations.

Thank you very much!

```
revfunc <- function(hist, growth){
    rval <- c()
    help <- c(hist)
    for(i in growth){
      help <- help*(1+i)
      rval <- c(rval, help)
    }
    return(rval)
}
```

Monte Carlo Simulations

```
pvffcf_function <- function(fcf0, growth, wacc){
  rval1 <- c()
  help <- c(fcf0)
  pvs <- rval1*(1/((1+wacc)^n))
  random_growth <- rnorm(n=10000, mean(fcfgrowth), sd(fcfgrowth))
  wacc <- rnorm(n=10000, 0.03804, 0.007711)
  pvffcf <- sum(freecashflows)  
  for(i in growth){
    help <- help*(1+i)
    rval1 <- c(rval1, help)
  }
  return(freecashflows)
}
```